# How to safety cast raw Map to Map<String, List<Int>> in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, dictionary, generics, casting, type-safety

I need a function which will cast `Map` to `Map<String, List<Int>>`

Currently I use unsafe "as" but I receive a fair warning about it. I want to fix it.

For list part I was able to implement function

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> List<*>.checkItemsAre(): List<T> {
    return this.filterIsInstance<T>().takeIf { it.size == this.size }
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("blablabla")
}
```

But I can't fund analog for map.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for something similar to the `checkItemsAre` for `List`s that you showed, you can write such a method for `Map`s.

```
inline fun <reified K : Any, reified V: Any> Map<*, *>.checkKeyValuesAre() =
    entries.associate {
        Pair(
            (it.key as? K) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException(),
            (it.value as? V) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException()
        )
    }
```

Just like `checkItemsAre`, this creates a *new* `Map` if all the keys are of type `K` and all the values are of type `V`.

However, this wouldn't completely check nested generics like `Map<String, List<Int>>`. If you want to handle that, you would have to add special cases for `List`, e.g.

```
return if (typeOf<V>().classifier == List::class) {
    val listElemType = typeOf<V>().arguments[0].type?.classifier as KClass<*>
    entries.associate {
        Pair(
            (it.key as? K) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException(),
            (it.value as List<*>).checkItemsAre(listElemType)
        )
    }
} else {
    // the code in the first code snippet...
}
```

```
fun <T : Any> List<*>.checkItemsAre(clazz: KClass<T>): List<T> {
    return this.filterIsInstance(clazz.java).takeIf { it.size == this.size }
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException()
}
```

If you are only going to handle maps with values of type `List`, I would just assume the map's values are lists:

```
inline fun <reified K : Any, reified E: Any> Map<*, *>. checkKeyAndListValuesAre() =
    entries.associate {
        Pair(
            (it.key as? K) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException(),
            (it.value as List<*>).checkItemsAre<E>()
        )
    }
```